# Trigonometry / Sum of two angles (α + β) if sinα = 8/17 and sinβ = 15/17

Tags: trigonometry

Find the sum of two angles **α** and **β** if **sinα = 8/17** and **sinβ = 15/17** if they are
**A)** *acute*
**B)** *obtuse*

How do you approach this problem? I'm stuck at the beginning. Please help.

Comment: The angles are complementary for a)....  $\sin(a) = 8/17$ so $\cos(a) = 15/17$ by Pythagorean identity.  $\cos(a) = \sin(b)$ so the angles are complementary.

Comment: Since $a+b=\pi/2$, for the obtuse case replace $a$ and $b$ with $\pi-a$ and $\pi-b$ and solve for $a+b$

Comment: and solve a + b - what? at the end of the sentence  @dardeshna

Answer (score 1):

In any problem like this where you are given the $\sin$ of an angle as a fraction, there is usually some involvement of Pythagoras' Theorem.

Imagine a right-angled triangle with opposite side length 8 and hypotenuse length 17. It will have the angle $\alpha$ with $\sin \alpha = \frac 8 {17}$. Find the other side...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is a simpler method.

**A) When the angles are acute**
When $\sin\alpha = \frac{8}{17} \implies \cos\alpha = \frac{15}{17}$.
When $\sin\beta = \frac{15}{17} \implies \cos\beta = \frac{8}{17}$.
$$\sin{(\alpha + \beta)}= \sin\alpha\cos\beta + \sin\beta\cos\alpha$$
Substituting the values above we get,
$$\sin{(\alpha + \beta)} = 1$$
$$\therefore \alpha + \beta = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

**B) When the angles are obtuse**
$$\sin{(\alpha+\beta)} = 1$$
$$\alpha + \beta = n\pi + (-1)^{n} \frac{\pi}{2}, n\in\Bbb{Z}$$
The angles selected from the set of solutions here must be greater than **$\frac{\pi}{2}$**.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sin(\alpha) = \frac{8}{17}\\
\sin(\beta) = \frac{15}{17}
$$
The sine of each of these angles are positive.
$$\alpha, \beta \in [0,\pi]$$

If they are acute then they lie between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.
If they are obtuse they lie between  $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi$

If the angles are obtuse, then they will be $\pi - \theta_a$ where $\theta_a$ is the acute angle.

$$ sin^{-1} \frac{8}{17} =~ .489$$
$$ sin^{-1} \frac{15}{17} =~ 1.080$$

$$\alpha_o =~ \pi - .489 =~ 2.65169265 $$
$$\beta_o =~ \pi - 1.080 =~ 2.061$$

Comment: You overlooked an obvious simplification that was hinted in the other answer and practically given on a silver platter in the comments under the question.

Comment: Specifically, what simplification?

Comment: The given angles are the angles of a $15,8,17$ Pythagorean triangle. Also see the answer posted about four hours after yours. The key point is you don't need to find the individual angles, only their sum.

Comment: You mean 4 hours before?

Comment: The trig identity Rash used is helpful and arrives at the same solution.